# How to find documents that contains a field that contains any sub-fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents that have an `attributes` field. Something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "somestring",
    ...,
    "attributes" : {
        "SomeKey" : {
            "code" : "SomeCode",
            "name" : "SomeName",
        }
    }
}
```

How do I find all documents that have an `attributes` field that have 1 or more sub-fields?

The above document would match but the below document would not.

```
{
    "_id" : "somestring",
    ...,
    "attributes" : {}
}
```

I know how to query for arrays that have a number of items, and query for documents that have a field that has some specific sub-field, but I'm looking for a document that has a field that has any sub-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$where` to run `.js` code thru query, you can use try as below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      attributes: {
        $ne: {}
      }
    }
  }
])

/** Or with `.find()` */

db.collection.find({ attributes: { $ne: {} } });
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ik4WEN7yeT)

Just in case if you don't have `attributes` at all or it exists but not an object then :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: [ { $type: "$attributes" } , "object" ] },
          { $ne: ["$attributes" , {} ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

/** Or with `.find()` */
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      { $eq: [{ $type: "$attributes" }, "object"] },
      { $ne: ["$attributes", {}] },
    ],
  },
});
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pgH9AUFh8Oz)

Comment: I didn't think to use aggregate. I like this better than my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kit : yes you can use ‘.find()’ as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found a mechanism that uses `$where`, but this can run slow because it's Javascript. None of the other built-in [operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) seem to fit.

```
db.getCollection('COL')
  .find({
      $where: function() {
        for (field in this["attributes"])
          return true;
        return false;
      }
  })
```